# Kafka same consumer group for message consumers as well as stream topology

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We run a clustered worker application that relies upon Kafka to consume messages using High-level consumer API. All nodes in a cluster share the same Consumer group. Now what we want is to migrate part of that logic to Kafka stream processor API. What is the approach here? Is stream topology going to fight with existing consumers over messages if assigned the same groupId/clientId? Should we assign different groupId/clientId? to stream topology? say "group." + "background-worker-stream"?

```
props.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "background-worker");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group." + "background-worker");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka Streams requires, uses & will insert the `application.id` property into the group ID. You cannot set the `group.id` explicitly for the Streams API, AFAIK

Comment: You are right. This is the comment from private static final String APPLICATION_ID_DOC = "An identifier for the stream processing application. Must be unique within the Kafka cluster. It is used as 1) the default client-id prefix, 2) the group-id for membership management, 3) the changelog topic prefix.";